# Model is invisible and with a smeared texture in the shading tab

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to texture my model. I go to shading tab where a background is displayed.

At first my model looks fine and grey but when I move my camera or pan and rotate, it disappears into smear . I ignore it and decide to add image texture on the nodes, and hook it to base color and sub surface color but the model is still invisible.

You can see my setting and icons that glow blue. Everything looks fine until this happens, and the texture never shows up.

Also, it only happens after I hook up the image texture node with the color and subsurface color.

So i kept testing and it only does it while I'm on material mode and render mode, but not in the cycles render engine.

It works in the solid view where you can see the texture.

Whats even the point to go to shading tab? and how do I know that the texture is actually there?

Because when i take this "textured" model to to another program like marvelous design, the texture is so scattered and messed up. THIS also happens with the default cube before I even use any nodes.

So my other question is how do i know the texture is actually there so other programs read it right? i have a hd graphics 620. could that be why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you didn't show the full Principled BSDF Node

Comment: i added it now.

Comment: What does the image texture look like? Why do you need the same image as color and subsurface? Did you unwrap the mesh to a UV map?

Comment: It's looks like a bug, or graphics card not supported. Can you provide information about graphics card?

Comment: its a skin. it does have a uv map. and im only assuming that since it does pull off in other modes correctly . hd graphics 620

Comment: Did you try experimenting with different Shaders? Does disconnecting the subsurface input change anything?

Comment: what are different shaders? and no disconnecting the subsurface doesnt change anything.